# Second Hadamard Variation Formula

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vector-analysis

For a symmetric matrix $H$ that depends smoothly on a variable $t$, let $u_i$ be the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.  From the definition 
$$
H(t) u(t) = \lambda_i(t) u(t)
$$
and $u(t)^T u(t) = 1$, we can easily take the derivative to find that
$$
H'(t) u(t) + H(t) u'(t) = \lambda_i'(t) u(t) + \lambda_i(t) u'(t)
$$
and
$$
u_i'^T u_i + u_i^T u_i' = 0.
$$
Taking the inner product of the first equation with $u_i$ and incorporating the second immediately yields
$$
\lambda'(t) = u_i(t)^T A'(t) u_i(t)
$$
which is known as Hadamard's first variation formula.  I would like to find a simple proof for Hadamard's second variation formula:
$$
\lambda_i''(t) = u_i(t)^T A''(t) u_i(t) + 2 \sum_{j \neq i} \frac{|u_j^T A'(t) u_i|^2}{\lambda_i -\lambda_j}.
$$
I tried taking two derivatives of the definitional equations but couldn't find a way to incorporate the other eigenvalues.  Also, we can assume that all the eigenvalues are distinct.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the equation you got $$ H'(t) u_i(t) + H(t)u_i'(t) = \lambda_i'(t)u_i(t) + \lambda_i(t)u_i'(t)$$
Dot product the whole equation with $u_j(t)$ for $j \neq i$, to get
$$ u_j(t)^\top H'(t) u_i(t) + \lambda_j(t)u_j(t)^\top u_i'(t) =  \lambda_i(t)u_j(t)^\top u_i'(t)$$
which simplifies to

$$u_j(t)^\top H'(t)u_i(t) = (\lambda_i(t) - \lambda_j(t))u_j(t)^\top u_i'(t) $$
Call this equation $\alpha$.

Now differentiate the equation you got for the first derivative of $\lambda_i(t)$, to get
$$ \lambda''_i(t) = u_i(t)^\top H''(t) u_i(t) + 2 u_i'(t)^\top H'(t) u_i(t)$$
Call this equation $\beta$.

Now, we know that $u_i'(t)$ is orthogonal to $u_i(t)$ and that the $u_i(t)$ form a orthonormal basis. So, we can write $$u_i'(t) =\sum\limits_{j \neq i} u_i'(t)^\top u_j(t) u_j(t)$$. Using equation $\alpha$, we get,
$$u_i'(t) =\sum\limits_{j \neq i} \frac{u_j(t)^\top H'(t) u_i(t)}{\lambda_i-\lambda_j} u_j(t)$$
Plugging this into the equation $\beta$, we get the desired equality.
Let me know if you have any questions.
Cheers